# GRUB update and multi linux

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I've got Windows 10 alongside with Debian, and recently I also installed Linux Mint. GRUB was installed in the first place by Debian.

- From what I've read, only one distro on a system "controls" GRUB settings (in my case Debian).
- From what I've tested it seems right: under Mint when I issue `grub-update`, nothing changes, not even changes made to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` of Mint. But when I issue `grub-update` from Debian, everything (Mint's stuff too) is up-to-date in GRUB menu.

I would like to finally only keep Mint and Windows, so I've searched how to have Mint to "control" GRUB settings.

It seems running `grub-install` from Mint would do the job, but there's no errors and changes made in Mint `/etc/default/grub` are not applied. I also still have the debian background in GRUB.

I didn't specified the device for `grub-install`, it's on a UEFI system and all OS partitions are on the the disk with the boot partition.

source:

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=98972

https://itsfoss.com/update-grub/

Am I missing something? Also, I wonder how each linux install knows if it is in charge of updating GRUB (kind of)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your system is UEFI, this is most likely caused by having Debian's GRUB before Mint's GRUB in the firmware boot order.

You can check this by running `efibootmgr -v` as root. The `BootCurrent` line will identify the bootloader that was most recently used to boot the system, the `BootOrder` specifies the order in which various configured boot options will be tried when the system is booting, and any `BootNNNN` (where `N` is a number) lines are the actual boot options.

To rearrange the boot options, use `efibootmgr -o XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ...` where `XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ...` is a comma-separated list of 4-digit numbers of boot options, in the desired order. To avoid firmware bugs, it might be safest to keep including all the same boot options that are in the original `BootOrder` setting, and just change their ordering.

Alternatively, you should go into BIOS boot settings, and move the boot option labeled "Ubuntu" or "Mint" before the option labeled "debian". That will achieve exactly the same thing as `efibootmgr -o ...` above.

Once you have Mint's GRUB as the first in the boot order, you now should have Mint's background in GRUB menus, indicating that Mint's GRUB is now doing the job. You should then verify that you can still boot Windows, and then you'll be ready to remove Debian's partitions.

After removing Debian, you should also delete its boot option using `efibootmgr -B -b XXXX`, where XXXX is the boot option number for Debian, and delete Debian's bootloader directory on the ESP partition, most likely by running `sudo rm -r /boot/efi/debian`.

Comment: *THAT* is an answer :) Thank you for so much details! efibootmgr -v results made be think about bios boot order. Under UEFI hard drive BBS priorities were listed "debian", "ubuntu" and "windows". Switched debian/ubuntu order and... Voilà! Now I know how to do it poweruser way ;)

Comment: I have the same problem. Although I changed the boot order and verified with `efibootmgr`, the system is still loading from Debian's `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. I am sure because of the grub colours and names in the menu. Should I also run `grub-install` after the change?

Comment: @fear If the other GRUB is before Debian in the boot order, but it still goes to Debian first, then something is causing the firmware to reject the other GRUB. The BootCurrent number in `efibootmgr -v` output should also refer to Debian's `BootNNNN` entry in that case. Do you have Secure Boot enabled, and if so, have you installed the packets `shim-signed` and/or `grub-efi-amd64-signed` in that other Linux?

Comment: @telcoM Yes, both packages are installed. The only difference I can see changing the BootNNNN order is that when I choose Debian as first the Grub shows version 2.02. When I choose Mint, the version is 2.04. But, the menu items are the same (those of Debian)!. I tried with supergrub2. This tool reads the entries correctly. I see that the entries from the Mint `grub.cfg` are different. When I choose (from the supergrub2 menu) to boot from either configuration all work well. To summarize, I think that if I delete the Debian partition I will not be able to boot Mint.